# Avoid break line when the field is empty breakline

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, html, line-break

I am using AMSCRIPT to personnalize some sender details in an email block at the end of the email. This block contains several lines  :

- name of the account
- first name, last name,
- phone
- email adress
- postal adress

I would like to avoid to display a break line if the fields are empty.

I had tried a code based on researchs I did in StackEchange but when I test it, I still have break lines in the empty fields. I have no doubt I am doing something wrong.

Here is the code I used on the beginning of the email :

```
%%[ 
var @accountname, @lastname, @firstname, @phone, @emailadress, @postaladress

SET @accountname = AttributeValue("Opportunity:Account:Name")
SET @lastname = AttributeValue("Opportunity:NomCommercial__c")
SET @firstname = AttributeValue("Opportunity:PrenomCommercial__c")
SET @phone = AttributeValue("Opportunity:TelephoneCommercial__c")
SET @emailadress = AttributeValue("Opportunity:EmailCommercial__c")
SET @postaladress = Concat(@Opportunity:Account:BillingStreet, "", @Opportunity:Account:BillingPostalCode, "", @Opportunity:Account:BillingCity)

%%=iif(not empty(@accountname),concat(@accountname,"<br/>"),"")=%%
%%=iif(not empty(@firstname),@firstname,"")=%%%%=iif(not empty(@lastname ),concat("",@lastname),"")=%%<br/>
%%=iif(not empty(@phone),concat(@phone,"<br/>"),"")=%%
%%=iif(not empty(@emailadress),concat(@emailadress,"<br/>"),"")=%%
%%=iif(not empty(@postaladress),concat(@postaladress,"<br/>"),"")=%%

endif 
]%%
```

On the email body at the bottom of the email I had added the output function  :

```
%%=v(@accountname)=%%
%%=v(@firstname)=%% %%=v(@lastname)=%%
%%=v(@phone)=%%
%%=v(@emailadress)=%%
%%=v(@postaladress)=%%
```

I do not know :

1. how to apply the iif condition that I had put on the beginning of the email with my v function
2. and if I have to use the v function to display only the fields that are not empty and not to display break lines between lines if the fields are empty.

Thanks for your precious help

Comment: just to be sure. depending on how your lower code snippet is entered into the email - unless you are entering the lower snippet into a plain HTML block (but e.g. a free form), it DOES contain line breaks between the `%%=v()=%%` functions.

Comment: Hi @JonasLamberty, I was using a text email thats'why but the code worked perfectly. I had put in on snippet block in a email and it worked.

Comment: ok :) then i'll formulate that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from your comment:

The line breaks that were physically entered between your variables are the problem. Since you previewed as text - pure text emails understand and display them as line breaks, while a HTML block / code snippet would only interpret actual `<br>`s as such >> hence this problem only occurred in plain text.

Maybe it's personal taste, but I would encourage to leave HTML out of AMPScript functions (iif / concat), myself I usually just write physical HTML and output variables between AMPscript blocks:

Something like:

```
%%[
/* establish variables like in your code ... */

/* concat first & last; trims leading and trailing spaces (in case one of them is empty, the space vanishes) */

SET @fullname = trim(concat(@firstname," ",@lastname))

/* conditional section where logic is separate from output */
if not empty(@accountName) THEN]%%%%=v(@accountname)=%%<br/>%%[endif]%%
%%[if not empty(@fullname) THEN]%%%%=v(@fullname)=%%<br/>%%[endif]%%
%%[if not empty(@phone) THEN]%%%%=v(@phone)=%%<br/>%%[endif]%%
%%[if not empty(@emailadress) THEN]%%%%=v(@emailadress)=%%<br/>%%[endif]%%
%%[if not empty(@postaladress) THEN]%%%%=v(@postaladress)=%%<br/>%%[endif]%%
endif 
]%%
```